# Mean of dictionaries by columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading from excel file Temperature sensor data using panda

data = pd.read_excel(file_path, skip_blank_lines=False, skiprows=1)

Then I convert data to dictionaries

```
    T_Data = {}
    T_Data['TW_A1'] = data['TW_A1']
    T_Data['TW_A2'] = data['TW_A2']
    T_Data['TW_F1'] = data['TW_F1']
    T_Data['TW_F2'] = data['TW_F2']
    T_Data['TW_F4'] = data['TW_F4'+"'"]
    T_Data['TW_S1'] = data['TW_S1']
    T_Data['TW_S2'] = data['TW_S2']
    T_Data['TW_S3'] = data['TW_S3']
    T_Data['TW_S4'] = data['TW_S4']
```

I'm trying to get the mean of the columns, but I just can get the mean of the sensors horizontally 
using the following code I can get the mean of only rows

```
 T_List = list(v[1:].mean() for k, v in temperature.items())
    print(T_List)
```

I have the data as

```
TW_A1 1---------
TW_A2 3---------
TW_F1 7----------
```

I want to get the mean of 1,3,7.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for dictionaries, just do pandas `mean` function

```
print(data[[i for i in data.columns.tolist() if str(i)[0]=='T']].mean())
```

Or since i don't super understand, see if this works:

```
print(data[[i for i in data.columns.tolist() if str(i)[0]=='T']].mean(axis=1))
```

Comment: I have another data including the temperature data

Comment: @andreahmed Okay, but then so what you want me to do?

Comment: so I can't do the mean over them

Comment: @andreahmed Understand. But then how does it look like?

Comment: You can see in the post, it's a list of dictionaries, I need to get the mean of the columns not of the rows

Comment: It takes the mean of other data too , and it takes the mean of the ROWS not the cols of the T_ data

Comment: @andreahmed Edited mine

Comment: Thanks, but The problem is the dataframe has ALSO other data, If I do what you did, it will get also the mean of the other data, which I don't want, that's why I convert panda data into a group of dictionaries seperatly

Comment: Then I wanted to get from the group of dictionaries the mean from column wise

Comment: @andreahmed what columns you want

Comment: all the columns that has T infront.

Comment: For example I have from dataframe
T1 1 2 3 4 5
T2 1 2 3 4  5
T3 1 2 3 4 5 
 I want the mean of 1+1+1/3  not  1+2+3+4+5

Comment: @andreahmed Edited mine

Comment: @andreahmed Edited mine

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @andreahmed Edited mine

Comment: @andreahmed Happy that i helped, 